# Creating a AWS NLB using kubectl with existing eks cluster and target groups

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks, aws-nlb

I have an EKS cluster with nodegroups created in AWS and now we need to create a NLB for that cluster as service

The problem is it's creating the NLB with new target group but we need use the target group which is already created manually

I tried the following code but its still creating the new target groups

Anything to be updated here

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
name: my-nlb-service
annotations:
service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-type: "nlb"
service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-cert: "arn:aws:acm:REGION:ACCOUNT_ID:certificate/CERTIFICATE_ID"
service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-target-groups: "443=arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:REGION:ACCOUNT_ID:targetgroup/TARGET_GROUP_ARN_443,8883=arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:REGION:ACCOUNT_ID:targetgroup/TARGET_GROUP_ARN_8883"
spec:
ports:
- name: https
port: 443
targetPort: 443
protocol: TCP
- name: mqtt
port: 8883
targetPort: 8883
protocol: TCP
selector:
app: your-app-label
type: LoadBalancer
loadBalancerSourceRanges:
- 0.0.0.0/0